# IE7 fails after reload of Orbited powered page

Tags: internet-explorer, comet, orbited

I am working on an [Orbited](http://orbited.org)-powered website and I'm experiencing some annoying behavior with IE7. Everything works fine and dandy in FF3, but in IE7, I get a recurring error if I reload the page:

```
Error: Can't execute code from a freed script
```

In other words, the site works in IE7 when you first browse to it, but breaks after a reload. I am running Orbited 0.7.0 and have followed [this tutorial](http://cometdaily.com/2008/10/10/scalable-real-time-web-architecture-part-2-a-live-graph-with-orbited-morbidq-and-jsio/) over at CometDaily. My code is identical to the tutorial code with the following exceptions:

1. I am not running the site on localhost, using a server with a real domain instead. All links are of course updated accordingly.
2. Static files(index.html) are served on port 80 by Django/Lighttpd rather than being served by Orbited deamon. Orbited is running on port 8000.

Now for the weird part. This problem does not occur if I am running on localhost.

I know Orbited.js creates one or two iframes to communicate with the Orbited deamon. I am guessing herein lies the problem somehow, but my knowledge in this area is limited.

So can anyone understand what is happening to my app? For the record, I have read about placing script tags after meta tags to avoid this problem. Sadly enough, it does not solve my problem. There aren't even any meta tags in the tutorial code, so I added one just to be sure.

BR // Fredrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use trunk (0.7.2). The problem has been solved.